# why two vectors is not similarity but result is 1?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, text-mining, cosine-similarity, bigdata

I'm using Cosine Similarity formula to caculate similarity between two vectors. I tried two different vectors like this:

**Vector1(-1237373741, 27, 1, 1, 331289590, 1818540802)**

**Vector2(-1237373741, 49, 1, 1, 331289590, 1818540802)**

Two vectors has a little different, but the result is **1**.

I don't know why? Anyone can explain this problem for me? thanks so much.

Comment: Can you show us the code you used to generate that result, as well as what you expect the result to be?

Comment: i tried my code and tried programs online at some websites, that is the same result, and i think my code is not wrong.

Comment: I think, if the result equal 1, that mean, two vectors is the same. but two vectors has a litte different, but the result is also 1.

Comment: I bet it's just a roundoff problem, since you're dealing with values on such different magnitudes. Would it benefit you to [scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling) your data?

Comment: What do you mean by, the result is 1? What calculation is involved?

Comment: Most likely you have a numerical precision problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, those two vectors are are pointing in the same direction (The larger coordinates are going to dominate the smaller differences in the other coordinate). A cosine similarity of ~1 is expected (Remember that cos(0) = 1)